# Send Ajax Requests vs Sending Entire Form By Id

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

The client should be able to send everything with a button, so I can do the following:

Send everything as form fields named like `invoiceId_detail_text` where `invoiceId` would be the id of the invoice, detail the part, and text the kind of field.

Example:

```
<form id="invoices" name="invoice">
   @foreach(var Invoce in Model.Invoices) {
       <div>
           <input type="number" id="@String.Format("{0}_amount", Invoice.InvoiceId)"/>
       </div>
       /*More Input Fields for the Invoice*/
       <div>
           <button type="submit"></button>
       </div>
   }
</form>
```

Or I can put every invoice separated in its own form, and send them by ajax, every form success I send the next one and so on.

Example:

```
@foreach(var Invoice in Model.Invoices) {
    string formName = String.Format("{0}_form", Invoce.InvoceId);
    <form id="@formName" class="invoiceForm" id="@formName" action="@Url.Action("EditIndividualInvoice","InvoicingEdit")">
        <input type="hidden" name="InvoiceId" value="@Invoice.InvoiceId"/>
           <div>
               <input type="number"/>
           </div>
           /*More Input Fields for the Invoice*/
    </form>
}
<button type="button" onclick="SendAllForms();">Send</button>
```

I did some research between some of my co-workers and many of them told me to just go with a post with all the invoices at the same time and then access every field by item id because I don't have knowledge of how many invoices are going to be sent, but i can get all of them by class on JQuery so it shouldn't be a problem.

I also read [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57599/when-should-i-use-ajax-to-submit-forms-vs-regular-page-submit) article from a UX point of view and it keeps me thinking about it.

By doing it with AJAX the cliend could be able to see a loading bar and it would be great, but if he closes the page the request would be incomplete and it could be complicated.

Which option could be better and why and what are the security implications of using one over another?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution depends principally of the behavior that you wish.

> By doing it with AJAX the cliend could be able to see a loading bar and it would be great, but **if he closes the page the request would be incomplete and it could be complicated**.

In the 2 solutions, if the user closes the page after clicking the button, this will not cancel the save. Once the request sent, it cannot be cancelled. So you shouldn't have "security" problems whatever the choosen solution.

The only thing you need to be careful, is to disable all AJAX buttons during an AJAX request, to avoid the user sending several request in the same time (that can provoke saving inconsistency data).

The classic solution is generally most simple to implement.
The AJAX solution can be most complicated to implement (more code), but provides a friendliest behavior.